# Reading in 3 lines of input

Tags: linux, bash

Lets say I have the following input in bash/linux

```
2
3
5
```

and I want to assign these lines to num1 num2 and num2 separately. How could I assign these variables? I know for sure it involves read but I don't know how to break apart what it reads.

Thanks!

Comment: `read -r a b c`? or `read -r num1 num2 num3`?

Comment: `read num1; read num2; read num3`

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by `input`?  as currently formatted it looks like you might be talking about 3 args provided on the command line, but upon editing the question it appears you have the 3 values on separate lines; or maybe you plan on reading the values from a file; how you plan on providing the input will determine what command(s) you may need to store the values into variables

Answer (score 0):

Since `read` reads a **line** (by default), you want 3 separate `read` commands:

```bash
read -r num1
read -r num2
read -r num3
```

You can read *all* the input into an array with the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) command.

```bash
mapfile -t nums
# then
echo "first:  ${nums[0]}"
echo "second: ${nums[1]}"
echo "third:  ${nums[2]}"
```

Comment: may want to make note of how to signal `mapfile` that you're done entering data; on my system I have to hit `^D` on a new (input) line

Answer (score 0):

run in bash $

```
needname() { i=0; while read num$i; do x=num${i}; echo "${!x}"; if [[ -z ${num}$i ]]; then break; fi;((i++)); done ; }
```

You can have a file (test.txt) with the content

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

And run

> needname < test.txt

Or you can input it with a pipe

```
echo -en "line1\nline2\nline3\n"|needname
cat test.txt|needname
```

Or simply type them in by hand ending with a blank line

> needname

Then > echo "$num0 $num1 etc"

You can put this function in a file script.sh and use it the same way